# HashMap Iteration only shows last element

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to implement an expandable listview with data coming from a database. I've already tried having the data added within the codes and it works so I'm now trying to have dynamic data from the database populate the listview.

The data is grouped in two, the main category and the member. For example if the main category is fruit, it's members may include mango, avocado, apples, etc. If animals, it may have horses, eagle, shark. The data always comes in pairs such as Animal, Horses; Animal, Eagle; Fruit, Apples. The expandable listview should appear as:

Animal

-- Horses

-- Eagle

Fruit

-- Apples

My code below can already determine the main group so the headers already display the main groupings of Fruit and Animal. By using

```
group_member.put(family_name, member_name);
```

I linked the member to the main category. My problem now is how to code for the iteration to group the members to the main category. So far I've already tried using iterator based on the sample codes given here in stackoverflow and from other sites however only the last elements of each group is display. I've also tried using the for-each loop bur still no success.

```
String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_COMPONENTS, "POST", params);
JSONArray components = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> componentList;
List<String> main_group = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, String> group_member = new HashMap<String, String>();

try {
  components = new JSONArray(json);

  if (components != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < components.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = components.getJSONObject(i);

      String family_name = c.getString(TAG_FAMILY_NAME);
      String member_name = c.getString(TAG_MEMBER_NAME);

      main_group.add(family_name);
      group_member.put(family_name, member_name);

      if (!listDataHeader.contains(main_group))
        listDataHeader.add(main_group);

      componentList.add(group_member);
    }
  }
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HashMap you can't have a key more than once in your list. Each key must be unique. 
This could be a solution:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> group_member = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

... using the Hashmap as a directory and the key is returning an Arraylist of the family members.

Comment: using your solution, how would I add the data to group_member?

Comment: and how to retrieve it. Thanks!